# Using ismember for symbolic variables in Matlab

Tags: matlab

When using ismember for small symbolic arrays I get the expected result.

For example:

```
syms a b c d e f
ismember([a,b,c],[e,f,a])
ans = 
1 0 0
```

However for larger arrays I get an error

```
ismember([a,b,c,d,e,f],[f,e,b,b,c,a])

Undefined function 'cumsum' for input arguments of type 'sym'.

Error in unique>uniquelegacy (line 411)
                    pos = cumsum([1;d]);        % Lists position, starting at 1.

Error in unique (line 95)
    [varargout{1:nlhs}] = uniquelegacy(varargin{1});

Error in ismember>ismemberlegacy (line 377)
                [au,~,an] = unique(a(:));

Error in ismember (line 76)
    [varargout{1:nlhs}] = ismemberlegacy(varargin{:});
```

Can you explain why this is? Is there a way around this for the larger symbolic arrays? Thanks!

Comment: Seems like a bug to me. It works fine in R2011b and R2013a but gives this error on R2012b. Seems to have something to do with the changes introduced in set operations like `unique` and `ismember` from R2011a.